# extract specific lines in text file using bash

Tags: bash, unix

i am running this command:

```
grep "folder1/folder2/folder3/.\*/results/.*.vcf.gz"         some_file.txt |grep ".vcf.gz$"  > vcffiles.txt
```

and  my output in the vcffiles.txt file is this :

```
folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4.1/results/B111.vcf.gz
folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4.2/results/B112.vcf.gz
folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4.1/folder6/folder7/results/B122.vcf.gz
folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4.1/folder6/folder7/folder8/results/B123.vcf.gz
```

i only want the first two lines and not the last two lines. How can i fix this code to get what i need?

Comment: `... | head -2 > vcffiles.txt`?

Comment: or `grep -m` if your grep supports it (`head -2` has the advantage of being POSIX, but this way you don't need to spawn another process)

Comment: Why do you want the first two? Are you looking for results without `folder6` of for files with `B11` or some other rule?

Comment: @WalterA  I am looking for *.vcf.gz files in results folder, without folder 6, 7 or 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the unwanted lines from your result with an additional filter.

```
... | grep -v "folder[678]"
```

Comment: what if there is a lot of additional folders and I can't list them all.

Comment: You just have to look for some pattern in common that will show what is additional. Perhaps `grep "folder1/folder2/folder3/[^/]*/results/*vcf.gz$"         some_file.txt` will the trick, or skip everything with more than 5 slashes.

Comment: In that case you can accept my answer. Good that it is solved.